# как вывести список всех папок и подпапок в директории php

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно получить в массив список всех подпапок, содержащихся в папке, при этом чтобы скрипт не отваливался при попытке зайти в папку, на которую у него нет прав на чтение, а также чтобы сохранял работоспособность от версии php 5.2 до версии 7.1.

Comment: может парсить выдачу exec(dir)?

Comment: не, мне именно нужен был простой, как кирпич, вариант, который будет работать независимо от версии пхп и настроек безопасности моего ресурса. в любом случае, я получил ответ на свой вопрос, благодарю )

Answer (score 1):

```
    $root = '/etc';

    $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
// при блоке прав чтения не отвалится
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied" (>>на которую у него нет прав на чтение)
    );

    $paths = array($root);
    foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
        if ($dir->isDir()) {
            $paths[] = $path;
        }
    }

    print_r($paths);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /etc
    [1] => /etc/rc2.d
    [2] => /etc/luarocks
    ...
    [17] => /etc/php5
    [18] => /etc/php5/apache2
    [19] => /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
    [20] => /etc/php5/mods-available
    [21] => /etc/php5/conf.d
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304935/php-listing-all-directories-and-sub-directories-recursively-in-drop-down-menu)

Можно смело использовать [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)  работает с (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7). Вот хороший пример с [glob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109100/2360072).

```
function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0)
   {
     $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
     foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
     {
       $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
     }
     return $files;
   }
```

И еще [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784144/2360072).

```
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            $results[] = $path;
        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            getDirContents($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

var_dump(getDirContents('/xampp/htdocs/WORK'));
```

Результат:

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string '/xampp/htdocs/WORK/iframe.html' (length=30)
  1 => string '/xampp/htdocs/WORK/index.html' (length=29)
  2 => string '/xampp/htdocs/WORK/js' (length=21)
  3 => string '/xampp/htdocs/WORK/js/btwn.js' (length=29)
  4 => string '/xampp/htdocs/WORK/js/qunit' (length=27)
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function)

Comment: спасибо большое, по ссылке на источник первого варианта лежит хорошее решение с названием функции expandDirectories, оно работает так, как мне нужно, правда в самом начале функции необходимо добавить сам стартовый каталог в массив, ну и почему-то собирает все папки по 2 раза, пришлось array_unique использовать, но в целом вариант подошёл.

Comment: @Ник если вариант вам подошел, отметьте его решением

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант glob без рекурсии

```
function AllFiles($dir)
{
    $files = glob($dir."/*.*",GLOB_NOSORT);
    do{
        $dir = $dir."/*";
        $files2 = glob($dir."/*.*",GLOB_NOSORT);

        $files = array_merge($files,$files2);
    }while(sizeof($files2)>0);

    return $files;
}
```